# Getting to the ThisWorkbook Code Area

Tags: excel, vba

From the normal Excel window, I can open the VBE and insert a new module by touching the key sequence: <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd>, <kbd>ALT</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>m</kbd> all without using the mouse.
Is there a way to open the VBE and navigate to the **ThisWorkbook** code area without using the mouse??

Comment: Have you tried: ALT+F11 ==> F7 ??

Comment: Seems you could also: holding ALT:  L then C. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a VBA project does NOT have modules then first <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> then,

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, <kbd>Home</kbd>, <kbd>End</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

The **Object Explorer** seems to get to *ThisWorkbook* code sheet reliably.

1. <kbd>F2</kbd>
2. Type *t·h·i·s·w·o·r·k·b·o·o·k*
3. <kbd>Enter</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

That relies on the Object Explorer opening with focus on the search criteria which is not *always* the case.

Comment: FYI, playing with `SendKeys` is known to diminish reasoning power substantially.

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> to jump to the project browser and then the arrow keys to select works for me.

Answer (score 1):

If the question is about without using a mouse, you could simply do Alt+F11 followed by Control+R to get to the project explorer, where you could locate ThisWorkbook by using the arrow keys.

If you want a repeatable sequence of characters that will always get you there, that is a more difficult problem.